# Which latex font does matplotlib need and how do I make it available?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, latex, ubuntu-16.04

The below error trace from running [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html) small example says that it cannot find the `cmr12` font. I found the following files in my system (Ubuntu 16.10):

```
./fonts/truetype/lyx/cmr12.ttf
./texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/cmr12.mf
./texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr12.tfm
./texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr12.pk
./texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb
./texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfm
./texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.afm
```

So, which font does matplotlib need and how do I make it available? Also, why does the font file that `matplotlib` is looking for does not have an extension?

Here is the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 45, in <module>
    d['ModDate'] = datetime.datetime.today()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2435, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2442, in close
    self._file.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 547, in close
    self.writeFonts()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 647, in writeFonts
    realpath, stat_key = get_realpath_and_stat(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 1038, in __call__
    stat = os.stat(realpath)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/meir/Dropbox/temp/cmr12'
```

**UPDATE** Here is the output after installing `cm-super`, emptying the cache and running with `--verbose-debug` as suggested by the comment of Gerard Rozsavolgyi:

```
$HOME=/home/meir
matplotlib data path /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data

*****************************************************************
You have the following UNSUPPORTED LaTeX preamble customizations:

Please do not ask for support with these customizations active.
*****************************************************************

loaded rc file /etc/matplotlibrc
matplotlib version 1.5.1
verbose.level debug
interactive is False
platform is linux2
loaded modules: <dictionary-keyiterator object at 0x7fa923c0d7e0>
CACHEDIR=/home/meir/.cache/matplotlib
Using fontManager instance from /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/fontList.cache
backend TkAgg version 8.6
findfont: Matching :family=sans-serif:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=400:stretch=normal:size=medium to Bitstream Vera Sans (u'/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf') with score of 0.000000
Assigning font /F1 = u'/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf'
findfont: Matching :family=sans-serif:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=400:stretch=normal:size=large to Bitstream Vera Sans (u'/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf') with score of 0.000000
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/1d97300a39adbdb822e515e35e631e34.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
find_tex_file(phvr7t.tfm): [u'kpsewhich', u'phvr7t.tfm']
find_tex_file result: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/helvetic/phvr7t.tfm
opening tfm file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/helvetic/phvr7t.tfm
lh=18, bc=0, ec=170, nw=17, nh=16, nd=16
find_tex_file(phvr7t.vf): [u'kpsewhich', u'phvr7t.vf']
find_tex_file result: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/adobe/helvetic/phvr7t.vf
Dvi: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/adobe/helvetic/phvr7t.vf
find_tex_file(phvr8r.tfm): [u'kpsewhich', u'phvr8r.tfm']
find_tex_file result: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/helvetic/phvr8r.tfm
opening tfm file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/helvetic/phvr8r.tfm
lh=18, bc=1, ec=255, nw=30, nh=16, nd=16
find_tex_file(phvr8r.vf): [u'kpsewhich', u'phvr8r.vf']
find_tex_file result: 
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Gamma'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Delta'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Theta'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Lambda'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Xi'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Pi'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Sigma'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Upsilon'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Phi'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Psi'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Omega'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `dotlessj'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `lslashslash'
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/d0e4b65f3cbceaa40d39cd0b4aa94322.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
find_tex_file(cmr12.tfm): [u'kpsewhich', u'cmr12.tfm']
find_tex_file result: ./cmr12.tfm
opening tfm file ./cmr12.tfm
lh=18, bc=0, ec=127, nw=34, nh=16, nd=10
find_tex_file(cmr12.vf): [u'kpsewhich', u'cmr12.vf']
find_tex_file result: 
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/1d97300a39adbdb822e515e35e631e34.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/04a76deccffda905e8691101fef1fc76.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/1d97300a39adbdb822e515e35e631e34.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/bbd64720c31d6f90a40311f23be42459.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/1d97300a39adbdb822e515e35e631e34.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/fe6359652f3a3d1ffea98277430a2e0d.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/1d97300a39adbdb822e515e35e631e34.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/4f1d4aac6b5a9606c9b7534411317104.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/1d97300a39adbdb822e515e35e631e34.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/75f66faa7396d6de47d7fef88d0cdf18.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/meir/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/d0e4b65f3cbceaa40d39cd0b4aa94322.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Assigning font /F2 = 'cmr12'
find_tex_file(pdftex.map): [u'kpsewhich', u'pdftex.map']
find_tex_file result: /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
Embedding font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf
Writing TrueType font
Embedding font cmr12
Writing TrueType font
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 49, in <module>
    d['ModDate'] = datetime.datetime.today()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2435, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2442, in close
    self._file.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 547, in close
    self.writeFonts()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 647, in writeFonts
    realpath, stat_key = get_realpath_and_stat(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 1038, in __call__
    stat = os.stat(realpath)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/meir/Dropbox/temp/cmr12'
```

Comment: You could check if the package cm-super is installed, delete the contents of the ~/.cache/matplotlib directory in your home and then launch your Python file with the --verbose-debug option at the end

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi The error persists. I have updated the post with the output from the run with `--verbose-debug`.

Comment: Which info related to latex is written in matplotlibrc? Add to this file "text.usetex : True  font.family : serif font.serif  : cm".

Comment: @Serenity I did not understand the advice: to which file should I add this line and where in the file should the line be placed?

Comment: read this topic http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Comment: @Serenity I appended the three lines that you gave to `/home/meir/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`.  I also checked that this is the configuration file that is read by using `matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`. The error persists.

Comment: Do you try `sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade`? Lastest version is 2.0. After update remove ~/.cache/matplotlib directory.

Comment: @Serenity All the relevant packages are upgraded, of course. I get the message: `Requirement already up-to-date: matplotlib in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. BTW, what's wrong with the question that it got voted down?

Comment: There are a lot of variables in the script (use of pdfpages, use of infodict, use of latex); reducing this even more and finding cases for which no error is thrown, might bring you closer to a solution. Next, it's unclear if this is a problem with the font itself, but you have no information in your question whether other fonts work or not.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The trace makes it pretty clear where the problem is. In addition, if the use of tex is turned off (i.e. `usetex=False`), the error disappears. As for trying another font, I don't know how to find out what fonts there are (just like I don't know where this font should appear)...

Comment: It's not clear where the problem comes from. It could still be either a  missing font in latex or the unability of the pdf backend to include the font into the pdf document. If you want to test, if the problem persits when not using pdf pages and saving to png instead, it might be helpful. Concerning fonts, you may try all kinds of things, e.g. `plt.rcParams["font.family"] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams["font.serif"] = ["Times New Roman"]`, where you want to replace `"Times New Roman"` with some fonts on your system.